# Class was missing valueDeclaration -OR- non-class had no interface declarations

Tags: angular, typescript

I was using angular version 10.2
After that i used angular update guide to update first to angular version 11.

So i run `ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11` and the migration to version 11 was sucessfull.
Now when i try to serve my application i get this error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Debug Failure. False expression: Class was missing valueDeclaration -OR- non-class had no interface declarations
See "C:\Users\A9783~1.BOS\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MvFW93\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

if i go in the location of the .log in AppData I get full error and it is

```
[error] Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Class was missing valueDeclaration -OR- non-class had no interface declarations
    at getOuterTypeParametersOfClassOrInterface (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50194:22)
    at getDeclaredTypeOfClassOrInterface (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50511:43)
    at tryGetDeclaredTypeOfSymbol (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50675:24)
    at getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50671:20)
    at getTypeOfGlobalSymbol (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53416:24)
    at getGlobalType (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53439:45)
    at initializeTypeChecker (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:76705:52)
    at Object.createTypeChecker (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:43116:9)
    at Object.getTypeChecker (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:103621:79)
    at new NgCompiler (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\core\src\compiler.js:204:79)
    at Function.NgCompiler.fromTicket (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\core\src\compiler.js:243:28)
    at new NgtscProgram (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\program.js:96:47)
    at AngularWebpackPlugin.updateJitProgram (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:427:36)
    at C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:163:24
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:1:1), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\xecm-migration-two\xecm\xecm-webapp-angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
```

Now after the update my package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "bootstrap.native": "3.0.13",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "html-lint": "^2.4.2",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.5.2",
    "t2i-scss": "1.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xcomponent-angular": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.8"
  },
```

what is the problem ? How can i resolve this ?

When i try ng --serve in my project file i get

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.19
Node: 14.15.5
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1002.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.19
@angular-devkit/core            10.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.19
@angular/cli                    11.2.19
@schematics/angular             11.2.19
@schematics/update              0.1102.19
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.3
```

Comment: Could you post the output of ng --version?

Comment: @AntonioVida Hello Antonio thank you for your response. I edited my question with ng serve output

Comment: Try to update typescript to 4.1 (For example: npm install typescript@4.1.5)´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by a bug in typescript. It can be fixed by upgrading to 4.1.x (e.g 4.1.5).

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19317